# Is there working a numerical rating system gem for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone know of a gem that allows users to rate a model that doesn't use a star system? I just want the users to be able to rate from `1 - 10`. Afterwards I could display the item's rating, e.g. `8.67`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want [acts_as_rateable](https://github.com/azabaj/acts_as_rateable)

Comment: It's kind of lacking documentation but it does seem like what I'm looking for!

Comment: How do I install this though? is there something user-friendlier qua installation?